# Oracle 8i trace of sql statements

Tags: sql, oracle, logging, oracle8i

I am investigating a legacy app that uses an Oracle 8i database in a test environment, specifically trying to find out what tables are accessed for read, insert, update or delete when the user performs an app function.

What is the best/easiest way to do this? Can I simply get a list of all sql statements sent to the database? Can I see when stored procedures are called?

Having little experience with Oracle but getting help from a DBA, I'm thinking I should either use a trace or look at the redo log with LogMiner, but how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to harvest the sql's from v$sql. If the SQL's are properly written - using bind variables - you should be able to catch most of the statements in a table for this. I currently have no running v8 at hand but this should be possible.

In order to get most of them, you probably need to repeat the harvesting during the various workloads that run on the database.

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't v$sql only contain the most recent sql statement? I need to capture all sql statements over a given time (~5 minutes). I'm told that to turn on tracing requires a server restart, so that's why I'm hoping I can somehow use the redo log...

Comment: In v$sql are all SQL statements that are used and that are not already flushed out of the SGA. You will miss only very short lived SQL's, that have no re-use and often have dirty literals.